# Problemas com DOM PDF PHP

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

Estou gerando um documento e esta aparecendo este erro:

> Call to undefined method Dompdf\FrameDecorator\TableRowGroup::get_cellmap()

Meu metodo de impressão esta desenvolvido assim:

```
 public function imprimircumpom(Request $request, $id)
{
    //$produto = Produto::find($request->input('COD_IDENT_PRODU'));
    $compra = \App\Compras::find($id);
    $d = new DNS1D();
    $d->setStorPath(__DIR__."/cache/");
    $html = '';
    $itensProdutos = "";
    $data = date("d/m/Y H:i:s",  strtotime($compra->created_at));

    foreach($compra->produtos as $produto){
        $itensProdutos = 
                '<tr>'.
                    '<td width="50%">'.
                        '<h5 class="text-uppercase f-400">'. $produto->item->TXT_NOMEX_PRODU.'</h5>'.
                        '<p class="text-muted">'. $produto->item->TXT_DESCR_PRODU.'</p>'.
                    '</td>'.
                    '<td>R$'. $produto->item->VAL_VENDA_PRODU.'</td>'.
                    '<td>'. $produto->QTD_PRODU_COMPR.'</td>'.
                    '<td class="highlight">R$'.  $produto->item->VAL_VENDA_PRODU * $produto->QTD_PRODU_COMPR.'</td>'.
                '</tr>';
    }

    $html = '<div class="card-body card-padding">'.
    '<div class="row m-b-25">'.
    '<div class="col-xs-6">'.
    '<div class="text-right">'.
    '<p class="c-gray">Loja</p>'.
    '<h4>SOFIA MODAS</h4>'.
    '<span class="text-muted">'.
    '<address>'.
    'Rua Antônio Luiz Costa, 56<br>'.
    'Quitandinha - Timóteo - MG'.
    '</address>'.
    '3848-3769'.
    '</span>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '<div class="col-xs-6">'.
    '<div class="i-to">'.
    '<p class="c-gray">Cliente</p>'.
    '<h4>'. $compra->cliente->TXT_NOMEX_CLIEN .'</h4>'.
    '<span class="text-muted">'.
    '<address>'.
    $compra->cliente->TXT_RUAXX_CLIEN.', '. $compra->cliente->TXT_NUMER_CLIEN .''.(($compra->cliente->TXT_COMPL_CLIEN == null) ? "": ", " .$compra->cliente->TXT_COMPL_CLIEN) .'<br>'.
    $compra->cliente->TXT_BAIRR_CLIEN.' - '. $compra->cliente->TXT_CIDAD_CLIEN.' -  '.strtoupper($compra->cliente->TXT_ESTAD_CLIEN).
    '</address>'.
    'Residencial: '. $compra->cliente->TXT_TELEF_RESID.'<br/>'.
    'Comercial: '. $compra->cliente->TXT_TELEF_COMER.'<br/>'.
    'Celular: '. $compra->cliente->TXT_TELEF_CELUL.'<br/>'.
    'Email: '. $compra->cliente->TXT_EMAIL_CLIEN .
    '</span>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '<div class="clearfix"></div>'.
    '<div class="row m-t-25 p-0 m-b-25">'.
    '<div class="col-xs-3">'.
    '<div class="bgm-amber brd-2 p-15">'.
    '<div class="c-white m-b-5">#Numero da venda</div>'.
    '<h2 class="m-0 c-white f-300">'. $compra->COD_DAXXX_VENDA.'</h2>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '<div class="col-xs-3">'.
    '<div class="bgm-blue brd-2 p-15">'.
    '<div class="c-white m-b-5">Data</div>'.
    '<h2 class="m-0 c-white f-300">'. $data .'</h2>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '<div class="col-xs-3">'.
    '<div class="bgm-'.  (($compra->STA_DAXXX_VENDA == 'S')? "green" : "red") .' brd-2 p-15">'.
    '<div class="c-white m-b-5">Status</div>'.
    '<h2 class="m-0 c-white f-300">'.  (($compra->STA_DAXXX_VENDA == 'S')? "Pago" : "Pendente").'</h2>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '<div class="col-xs-3">'.
    '<div class="bgm-red brd-2 p-15">'.
    '<div class="c-white m-b-5">Total da venda</div>'.
    '<h2 class="m-0 c-white f-300">R$'. $compra->VAL_TOTAL_VENDA.'</h2>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '</div>'.
    '<div class="clearfix"></div>'.
    '<table class="table i-table m-t-25 m-b-25">'.
    '<thead class="text-uppercase">'.
    '<th class="c-gray">DESCRIÇÃO DO PRODUTO</th>'.
    '<th class="c-gray">VALOR POR UNIDADE</th>'.
    '<th class="c-gray">QUANTIDADE</th>'.
    '<th class="highlight">TOTAL</th>'.
    '</thead>'.
    '<tbody>'.
    '<thead>'.
    $itensProdutos.
    '<tr>'.
    '<td colspan="3"></td>'.
    '<td class="highlight">'.
    (($compra->QTD_PORCE_DESCO == 0)? "" : $compra->QTD_PORCE_DESCO . "% OFF <br>").
    'R$'. $compra->VAL_TOTAL_VENDA.''.
    '</td>'.
    '</tr>'.
    '</thead>'.
    '</tbody>'.
    '</table>';

    $documentTemplate = '
    <!doctype html> 
    <html> 
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.example.com/style.css">
    </head> 
    <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    '.$html.'
    </div>
    </body> 
    </html>';

    if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
        $documentTemplate = stripslashes($documentTemplate);


    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($documentTemplate);
    $dompdf->set_paper("a7", "portrail");
    $dompdf->render();

    return $dompdf->stream("nv". date("dmY"). "-"  . $id);
}
```

Importei as seguintes classe para utilização:

```
use \Milon\Barcode\DNS1D;
use Fpdf;
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
use Dompdf\Options;
```

O que pode esta acontecendo ?